# Missing max_parallel_degree configuration parameter in PostgreSql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-9.6

I am not able to `set max_parallel_degree`.

Documentation: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Parallel_Query

Just now I updated my postgresql test database server from version **9.5.5** to **9.6**. Server is restarted, up and running. According documentation I should be able to set **parallel degree** for actual user, but this parameter is not in configuration table.

When I try to `set max_parallel_degree = 4;` I get this:
**ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "max_parallel_degree"**

**My configuration:**
ubuntu server (updated), postgresql 9.6 in VirtualBox machine with 6 cores assigned.
My config file: /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf does not contain rows with "parallel" word.
server_version = 9.6.1; psql version = 9.6.1

```
select * from pg_settings where name like '%par%';
```

*Results:*

```
debug_print_parse               | off
force_parallel_mode             | on  *
log_parser_stats                | off
max_parallel_workers_per_gather | 4   *
max_prepared_transactions       | 0
min_parallel_relation_size      | 1024
parallel_setup_cost             | 1000
parallel_tuple_cost             | 0.1
```

*This settings was set by me after run psql.

What can I do to enable parallel query running on PostgreSql 9.6?

Comment: That wiki page seems essentially a draft of the real documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/parallel-query.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `max_parallel_degree` has been renamed to `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`.

> Additionally, we've made some user-visible changes to parameters and
>   functions. These may cause dump/restore between beta 1 and beta 2 to
>   generate errors. This includes:
>
> rename max_parallel_degree to max_parallel_workers_per_gather

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1677/

Comment: OMG news id 1677 is really hidden place to post this information instead of wiki.postgresql.org... Thanks.